# Factory pattern with objects that have many optional properties

Tags: c#, factory

I'm refactoring a class that represents the data in some XML. Currently, the class loads the XML itself and property implementations parse the XML every time. I'd like to factor out the XML logic and use a factory to create these objects. But there are several 'optional' properties and I'm struggling to find an elegant way to handle this.

Let's say the XML looks like this:

```
<data>
    <foo>a</foo>
    <bar>b</bar>
</data>
```

Assume both foo and bar are optional. The class implementation looks something like this:

```
interface IOptionalFoo
{
    public bool HasFoo();

    public string Foo { get; }
}

// Assume IOptionalBar is similar
public class Data : IOptionalFoo, IOptionalBar
{
    // ...
}
```

(Don't ask me why there's a mix of methods and properties for it. I didn't design that interface and it's not changing.)

So I've got a factory and it looks something like this:

```
class DataFactory
{
    public static Data Create(string xml)
    {
        var dataXml = new DataXml(xml);

        if (dataXml.HasFoo())
        {
            // ???
        }

        // Create and return the object based on the data that was gathered
    }
}
```

This is where I can't seem to settle on an elegant solution. I've done some searching and found some solutions I don't like. Suppose I leave out all of the optional properties from the constructor:

- I can implement Foo and Bar as read/write on Data. This satisfies the interface but I don't like it from a design standpoint. The properties are meant to be immutable and this fudges that.
- I could provide SetFoo() and SetBar() methods in Data. This is just putting lipstick on the last method.
- I could use the internal access specifier; for the most part I don't believe this class is being used outside of its assembly so again it's just a different way to do the first technique.

The only other solution I can think of involves adding some methods to the data class:

```
class Data : IOptionalFoo, IOptionalBar
{
    public static Data WithFoo(Data input, string foo)
    {
        input.Foo = foo;
        return input;
    }
}
```

If I do that, the setter on Foo can be private and that makes me happier. But I don't really like littering the data object with a lot of creation methods, either. There's a LOT of optional properties. I've thought about making some kind of DataInitialization object with a get/set API of nullable versions for each property, but so many of the properties are optional it'd end up more like the object I am refactoring becomes a facade over a read/write version. Maybe that's the best solution: an internal read/write version of the class.

Have I enumerated the options? Do I need to quit being so picky and settle on one of the techniques above? Or is there some other solution I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did:

I created a new class that represented a read/write interface for all of the properties. Now the constructor of the Data class takes an instance of that type via the constructor and wraps the read/write properties with read-only versions. It was a little tedious, but wasn't as bad as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of such keywords as virtual/castle dynamic proxy/reflection/T4 scripts - each one can solve the problem on a slightly different angle.

On another note, this seems perfectably reasonable, unless I misunderstood you:

```
private void CopyFrom(DataXml dataXml) // in Data class
{
    if (dataXml.HasFoo()) Foo = dataXml.Foo;
    //etc
}
```